# Creating a BizTalk solutions with multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk

Has anyone got any guidance, better yet, tools for generating up a "starter" BizTalk solution ?

I've been reading various blogs, articles, etc. and they mainly go for splitting down the solution into seperate projects, one for schema, one for orchestrations, etc.

I'd like to follow this practice, but it's a pain creating the full set, so I'm wondering if there is someway to easily set this up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think I've hit pay dirt, check out the BizTalk Software Factory at [BSF](http://bsf.codeplex.com/)

One gotchya, make sure you get the correct versions of the GAT ...

 - the MSI installer points you at the July 2007 page

 - but you need the Feb 2008 versions

 - there are links at [correct GAT](http://bsf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=34226)

Answer (score 1):

We use applications to split on functional areas, then projects to split on artefact types.

Answer (score 0):

You'll be a lot happier in the long run if you organize your projects around functional areas rather than artifact type.  Otherwise I am afraid you'll find change management a nightmare.  More recently  People are trending towards subdivision of projects into folders for artifact types.

Comment: I can see the idea, but all the blogs / examples I've looked at have the split on artifacts.
That said, I can see you'd have functional as a top level, and then below that have the artifacts

Answer (score 0):

I think its a question of dependencies, deployment and accepted downtime. If you split maps, schemas and orchestrations you have no chance to deploy different processes independently. Therefor having "isolated" integration domains make more sense. BizTalk projects should be created by functionality and contains all necessary artifacts. Extract shared resources and define a deployment order to fit dependencies.

In terms of downtime keep in mind that you have to restart host instances after deployment which possibly affect other integration processes.